# Disabiling 'X mark' in IE11 compatibility mode

Tags: html, css, gwt

Iam working on GWT, tried to disable the 'x mark' which is appearing in IE11.
By adding the following code in CSS. But could not disable 'x mark'.

```
::-ms-clear
{
    display: none;
    width : 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

I also tried the following tag in the html page.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

I got the following info message.
"Your *.gwt.xml module configuration prohibits the use of the current doucment rendering mode (document.compatMode=' CSS1Compat').
Modify your application's host HTML page doctype, or update your custom 'document.compatMode' configuration property settings".

Please suggest on how to disable this 'x mark'

P.S: Using IE11 browser in compatibility mode with document mode as 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

::-ms-clear doesn't work in compatibility mode.

Comment: I got to know that, is there any other way to disable 'x mark' in compatibility mode.

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry.